# How to get acces to block parameters defined in XML layout in block class

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks

I am wondering how I can get access to parameter for blocks I define in a layout.xml

My `cms_index_index.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="intro.main.top">
            <container name="intro.main.top.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="intro-main-top-container" before="-">
                <block class="Test\PromoBanners\Block\Container"
                    name="ambanners.test.home.primary" template="container.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="position" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
                        </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Test\PromoBanners\Block\Container"
                    name="ambanners.test.home.primary.sidebar" template="container.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="position" xsi:type="string">25</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

In the two blocks I pass `position` as an argument.

In the `container.phtml` I have access to `position` with just calling `$this->getData('position)`. But in my block class I do not.

My `Blocks\Container.php:

```
<?php

namespace Test\PromoBanners\Block;

use Test\PromoBanners\Model\Banner\Data;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Container extends Template
{
    private $layerResolver;

    private $bannerModel;

    private $banners;

    public $positions;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        Data $bannerModel,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->bannerModel = $bannerModel;
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
        $this->banners = $this->getBanners();
        $this->positions = $this->getData('position');
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        var_dump($this->positions) // dumps nothing
    }
}
```

I need the `position` parameter to do some logic with and looking up other blocks. Something I do not want to do in the `container.phtml` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get block parameter by using below code.

```
$this->getPosition();
```

**I hope it will help !!**

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This also returns `null` for me.

Comment: Can you please once print all data and check
`echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->getData());`

Comment: `[
{ },
"</pre>"
]`

But I dare the believe the fist time i refreshed the position was there. Obviously I did do a `bin/magento cache:flush` to make sure nothing was cached

Answer (score 0):

Just use`$block->getPosition()` at phtml and `$this->getPosition()` atr block class.